# How to copy the file from other App to ma App's documents directory in iOS?

Tags: ios

I create a App named **Reader** , and I try to read the text file via my App from the other Application , ex: read text file from google driver , e-mail , dropbox.

I reference the following link to add my App into "open in..." list when I press the text file on e-mail , google driver or dropbox.

[How do I get my application to show up in the "Open in..." menu on iOS for a specific document type?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html)

For example: I receive the file from e-mail like the following picture.

[[image]]

When I press on the text file , it show the content. And it show like the following picture when I press the share button on the upper right corner.
And it can choose to open the text file via my App(**Reader**)

[image]

After I choose my **Reader** app , the **Reader** will open. And I want to read the content of text file. But I have no idea what to do...

**How to read the content of text file after my Reader App open ?**

**Should I copy the text file to my App's documents directory first ?** 
How to copy ? I didn't get the text file path or any object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AppDelegate` add the method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool { ... }
```

You will be passed the `NSURL` of the file which is being opened in your application, you can use that `NSURL` to access the file using something like `NSString` or `NSData`

```
// NSData 
init?(contentsOfURL url: NSURL)

// NSString 
convenience init?(contentsOfURL url: NSURL, encoding enc: UInt, error: NSErrorPointer)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much !! It is helpful.